# Custimizing styles of WMD Editor's Header

Tags: wmd-editor

How can i custimize the styles of WMD editor's header similar to the one used here in stack overflow

Answer (score 0):

I recently used the [markitup](http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/home/) editor and found the skin implementation pretty useful.  Each skin has its own images and styles which you can easily override if you need to.  The editor is also jQuery-driven, which is nice if you're used to that syntax.  Check it out.